# Escaping &hellip; with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, escaping, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I am currrently using BeautifulSoup to scrape some websites, however I have a problem with some specific characters, the code inside UnicodeDammit seems to indicate this (again) are some Microsoft-invented ones.

I'm using the newest version of BeautifulSoup(3.0.8.1) as I am still using python2.5

The following code illustrates my problem:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('...Baby One More Time (Digital Deluxe Version&hellip;')
print soup

'...Baby One More Time (Digital Deluxe Version&hellip;'
```

As you can see the problem is the '…'(&hellip) character at the end (which your browser probably escaped correctly). Obviously that's not what I am interested in.

It would be nice to have this characters unicode representation or something.
Even sinmply ignoring it would solve my particular problem.

How can I do this with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('...Baby One More Time (Digital Deluxe Version&hellip;', convertEntities="html")
```

Answer (score 1):

MS may have invented it, but `&hellip;` is part of HTML 4: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html

Perhaps your `Lib/htmlentitydefs.py` is missing or out-of-date, as that's what BeautifulSoup uses to convert entities.

If you look at [the Python 2.5 source tree](http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/tags/r255/Lib/htmlentitydefs.py?revision=51333&content-type=text%2Fplain) you will clearly see it defined on line 126.